# nested dropdowns in knockoutj2 what am i doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

OK I am trying to get my head around knockoutjs nested dropdowns.

Basically I want to select an option from a binded dropdown a, and have dropdown b display the related options.

Here is the model which i have pinched from the knockout tutorial and amended:

```
 function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
            var self = this;
            self.name = name;
            self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
        }

        // Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
        function ReservationsViewModel() {
            var self = this;

            // Non-editable catalog data - would come from the server
            self.availableMeals = ko.observableArray([
                { mealName: "Standard (sandwich)", price: 0, Sizes: [{ Desc: "large" }, { Desc: "medium" }, { Desc: "small" }] },
                { mealName: "Premium (lobster)", price: 34.95, Sizes: [{ Desc: "large1" }, { Desc: "medium1" }, { Desc: "small1" }] },
                { mealName: "Ultimate (whole zebra)", price: 290, Sizes: [{ Desc: "large2" }, { Desc: "medium2" }, { Desc: "small2" }] }
            ]);


            // Editable data
            self.seats = ko.observableArray([
                new SeatReservation("Steve", self.availableMeals[0]),
                new SeatReservation("Bert", self.availableMeals[0])
            ]);


        }

        ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

Then my html:

```
<tbody data-bind="foreach: seats">
    <tr>
        <td><input data-bind="value: name" /></td>
        <td><select data-bind="options: $root.availableMeals, value: meal, optionsText: 'mealName'"></select></td>
         <td data-bind="with: $root.availableMeals">
                    <select data-bind='options: $parent.Sizes, optionsText: "Desc", optionsCaption: "Select...", value: Desc'> </select>
                </td>
        <td data-bind="text: meal().price"></td>
    </tr>    
</tbody>
```

Now I know my html is probably not right as I have messed with a lot to try and get this working but basically I want to select a meal from the dropdown and have its relevant sizes display in the 2nd dropdown...

What am I doing wrong?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, all of the `SeatReservation` objects point to potentially the same copy of the `availableMeal` items.

If each reservation is able to customize the "size", then you would likely want to store the size on the reservation object.  Maybe like:

```
function SeatReservation(name, initialMeal) {
  var self = this;
  self.name = name;
  self.meal = ko.observable(initialMeal);
  self.size = ko.observable();
}
```

Then you can bind like:

```
  <td data-bind="if: meal">
    <select data-bind='options: meal().Sizes, optionsText: "Desc", optionsCaption: "Select...", optionsValue: "Desc", value: size'></select>
  </td>
```

Sample here: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/HsDeG/

Comment: OK so that works perfect thanks and seeing it running here on my machine makes things a bit clearer too!!